# Python: Solution for the N-Queen puzzle to check the diagonals

Tags: python, matrix, n-queens

Here I have to code the N-Queens problem, where the user will input the dimension of the chessboard and the positions of the Queens.

```
Enter the dimension of the Chessboard: 4
Enter position of the Queen: 10
Enter position of the Queen: 31
Enter position of the Queen: 02
Enter position of the Queen: 23
```

And from the user input I have made the candidate solution(which is a list) where the index of the candidate solution represent the column of the Queen and the value represent the row position of the Queen.

The candidate solution is as follows:
    `[1, 3, 0, 2]`

From that I have made a matrix to represent the positions of the Queens:

```
0, 0, 1, 0
1, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 1
0, 1, 0, 0
```

My problem is I have to check whether the candidate solution is true, by checking the diagonals and print a message if the solution is true.

Here is my code so far which will print the candidate solution and the matrix showing the positions of the Queens:

```
#Ask the user to input the dimension of the Chessboard(N)
N=int(input("Enter the dimension of the Chessboard: "))

#Creating a list of list with zeros in the dimension N*N
list_0=[0 for m in range(N)]

#Iterating for the length of N
for t in range(N):

    #Creating a list for the input position values
    position=[int(i) for i in input("Enter position of the Queen: ")]

    x,y = position[0],position[1]

    #The y position is the index of the list_0, where x is the value at the index position
    list_0[y] = x

#Printing the list_0
print(list_0)

#Creating a list of list with zeros
list_matrix = [[0 for m in range(len(list_0))] for n in range(len(list_0))]

#Iterating through the list_0 to find the index and the value of the list_0
for element in range(len(list_0)):

    x,y = element, list_0[element]

    list_matrix[y][x] = 1

#Defining a list to print the candidate solution for N-Queen problen in matrix format
def printListInTableFormat(list_default):

    #Looping through length of the list_default
    for row in range(len(list_default)):

        new_row=''.join(str(list_matrix[row]))

        matrix=print(new_row.strip('[]'))

    return matrix

#Printing the matrix
matrix = printListInTableFormat(list_matrix)
```

Since I'm new to Python, any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once you're done, it would be interesting to compare to this solution:  http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576647/

Comment: Hmm, this question and the answers seem to be attracting downvotes.  The OP put in a good effort and both answers steer the OP toward a correct solution.  Not sure I see what the problem is.

Comment: Questions about games seem to attract automatic downvotes from some quarters.

Answer (score 5):

### Hint

A queen at `(p, q)` is on the same diagonal as a queen at `(r, s)` on when `abs(p - r) == abs(q - s)`.

Answer (score 0):

See [@Raymond Hettinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1001643/raymond-hettinger)'s hint for the reasoning to this, but basically, for every x (columns are x-coordinates and also the index values of the `N` array) in the input list of `N = [1, 3, 0, 2]`, check all the other chess pieces to see how their x (columns) and y (rows) coordinates compare.

```
def is_valid(N):
    size = len(N)
    for x in range(size):
        for col in range(x + 1, size):
            if abs(x - col) == abs(N[x] - N[col]):
                return False
    return True
```

or lil bit cleaner, this checks if all values are true for all checks the difference checks:

```
def is_valid(N):
    for x in range(size):
        return all(abs(x - row) != abs(N[x] - N[row]) for row in range(x + 1, size)
```

A diagonal should not be the only validity test though.  You should also add this check, `len(N) == len(set(N))`.  This makes sure that there are no queens in the same row.

Answer (score -2):

A simple variante

```
import random

global maX
global maY
global mostAttacks
global posInVector
#1.
def GenM(N):
    p=[[" " for x in range(0,N)]for x in range(0,N)]
    #print(p)
    return p;

def fillPos():
    p=[[[] for x in range(0,2)]for x in range(0,N)]
    #print(p)
    return p;

N=4
matrix=GenM(N)
places = fillPos()
posInVector = 0

def randomPlace(N):
    for x in range(0,N):
        xpos = random.randint(0,N-1)
        ypos = random.randint(0,N-1)
        matrix[xpos][ypos]='R'
        places[x][0] = xpos
        places[x][1] = ypos

randomPlace(N)

print(places)

def printMatrix():
    print("---------------------------------\n")
    for i in matrix:
        print(i)
        print("\n")
printMatrix()

# == Generate random position , geterate random pos for N queens 
# and display the matrix and the array for the queen's positions

def VerifLine(L):
    queens = 0
    line=matrix[L]
    for element in line:
        if(element=='R'):
            queens+=1
        if(queens == 2):
            return 1;
    return 0;

#print(VerifLine(0))

def VerifCol(C):
    queens = 0
    for element in range(0,N):
        if(matrix[element][C]=='R'):
            queens+=1
        if(queens == 2):
            return 1;
    return 0;


def VerifDiagonalStg(L,C):
    #print("down left")
    j = C-1
    for i in range(L+1,N):
        if j < N and j >= 0:
            if matrix[i][j] == 'R':
                return 1
            j-=1      
    #print("---")

    #print("up right")
    j = C+1
    for i in range(L-1,-1,-1):
        if j < N and j >= 0:
            if matrix[i][j] == 'R':
                return 1
            j+=1
    #print("---")

    return 0

def VerifDiagonalDr(L,C):
    #print("down right")
    j = C+1
    for i in range(L+1,N):
        if j < N and j >= 0:
            if matrix[i][j] == 'R':
                return 1
            j+=1
    #print("---")

    #print("up left")
    j = C-1
    for i in range(L-1,-1,-1):
        if j < N and j >= 0:
            if matrix[i][j] == 'R':
                return 1
            j-=1
    #print("---")

    return 0


maX = -1
maY = -1
def countAttacks(qx, qy):
    '''print("queen: ", qx, " ", qy)
    print("pe line: ",VerifLine(qx))
    print("pe col: ", VerifCol(qy))
    print("pe diagonal: ", VerifDiagonalDr(qx,qy) + VerifDiagonalStg(qx,qy))
    print("\n=============\n")'''
    attacks = VerifLine(qx) + VerifCol(qy) + VerifDiagonalDr(qx,qy) + VerifDiagonalStg(qx,qy)
    return attacks

def findMostAttacked(places):
    global maX
    global maY
    global mostAttacks
    global posInVector
    mX = places[0][0]
    mY = places[0][1]
    maxAttacks = countAttacks(places[0][0], places[0][1])
    for i in range(1,N):
        if maxAttacks < countAttacks(places[i][0], places[i][1]):
            mX = places[i][0]
            mY = places[i][1]
            maxAttacks = countAttacks(places[i][0], places[i][1])
            posInVector = i
    print("most attacked: ", mX, " ", mY)
    maX = mX
    maY = mY
    mostAttacks = maxAttacks
    print("attacks: ", maxAttacks)
    if mostAttacks == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

def moveMostAttacked():
    global maX
    global maY
    global mostAttacks
    global posInVector
    for i in range(0,N):
        for j in range(0,N):
            if(matrix[i][j] == " "):
                attacksForThisPos = countAttacks(i,j)
                if(attacksForThisPos < mostAttacks):
                    matrix[maX][maY] = " "
                    matrix[i][j] = 'R'
                    places[posInVector][0] = i
                    places[posInVector][1] = j
                    print('poz in vector: ', posInVector)
                    print(matrix[maX][maY], "->", matrix[i][j])
                    print('mutata de pe ',maX, ' ',maY, ' pe ', i,' ',j)
                    print('nr vechi de atacuri: ', mostAttacks)
                    print('nr nou de atacuri: ', attacksForThisPos)
                    return 0

while(findMostAttacked(places) == 1):
    findMostAttacked(places)
    moveMostAttacked()
    printMatrix()
    input("Press Enter to continue...")


print(" ========== ")
```

Comment: Committed the voyage -  bit.ly/comispy